# JQuery Validation plugin issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validate plugin. It is a simple form on my site which is in MVC 4

```
<form name="profileForm" id="profileForm" action="@Url.Content("~/myprofile")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" class="name input" placeholder="First name" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="@Request["FirstName"]"/>
                <input type="text" class="company input" placeholder="Last Name" name="LastName" id="LastName" value="@Request["LastName"]"/>
                <textarea class="tarea input" placeholder="About" name="AboutUser">@Request["AboutUser"]</textarea>
```

and using some client side scripts

```
 </body>
</html>        



    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


         <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/additional-methods.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#profileForm').validate({
            rules: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                },
            }
        });

   });




    </script>
```

Things work fine when I add "required" class to the "FirstName" field and validate plugin can properly validate it. However, when I do not do so (As I have done in the code given above), validate plugin simply does not work. Is there something I am missing or there are some constrains in the validation plugin.

Comment: The code you've shown above should work.   What does the *rendered* HTML look like?   Maybe the field `name` attribute is different when the page renders.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `</form>` tag and your code is working perfectly fine.  Perhaps your *rendered* HTML looks different than you expect.

```
Browser -> View Source
```

... and make sure the `name` attribute for each field matches the `name` you've specified within `.validate()` for your `rules`.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/skt3b/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#profileForm').validate({
        rules: {
            FirstName: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="profileForm" name="profileForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="name input" placeholder="First name"  value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" class="company input" placeholder="Last Name"  value=""/>
    <textarea name="AboutUser" class="tarea input" placeholder="About"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```